# Loading a php file on ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got a div class called news. It contains some updates from users. When a user submits a new update, I want this new update to be appear at the top of the news class since it's new.

I tried the following, but it doesn't work the way I want. When I submit the form, latestpost.php gets loaded but news div disappears (because my prepend() is empty.)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#new').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var formData = form.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/modules/feed/process.php', // the url where we want to POST
            data: formData, // our data object
            success: function () {
                $("#statustext").val(''); // I reset textarea's value here
                $(".news").prepend().load("/modules/feed/latestpost.php"); // problematic part
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You could return the latest post in the response of process.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try substituting `$.ajax()` for `.load()` , utilizing `context` setting with `$(".news")` as value

```
$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url:"/modules/feed/latestpost.php",
  context:$(".news") // `$(".news")` : `this` within `.then()`
})
.then(function(data) {
  this.prepend(data); // `this`:`$(".news")`
}, function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(errorThrown)
});
```